# tally number of duplicates and put them in a column in a data frame

Tags: r, count

I want to count the number of duplicates in a column and add them in another column to the data base.

For example, some data

```
a <- c(1,1,2,3,4,4)
b <- c("A","A","C","C","D","D")

df <- data.frame(a,b)
```

This is the result I am looking for:

```
  a b count
1 1 A     1
2 1 A     2
3 2 C     1
4 3 C     1
5 4 D     1
6 4 D     2
```

Comment: Why did the `dpylr` answer get deleted? It worked well for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df$count = sequence(rle(df$a)$lengths)
df
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df$count <- with(df, ave(rep(1, nrow(df)), b, a, FUN = cumsum))
```

Comment: with(df, ave(a, b, a, seq_along))

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, count := seq_len(.N), .(a, b)]
df
#    a b count
#1: 1 A     1
#2: 1 A     2
#3: 2 C     1
#4: 3 C     1
#5: 4 D     1
#6: 4 D     2
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but only needed to count duplicates based on the information in 1 column. user7298145's answer worked well for a small data frame, but my data has ~20k lines and failed with the error:

```
Error: memory exhausted (limit reached?)
Error during wrapup: memory exhausted (limit reached?)
```

So I created a `for` loop that did the trick:

```
##  order the values that are duplicated
primary_duplicated <- primary_duplicated1[order(primary_duplicated1$md5), ]
##  create blank/NA column
primary_duplicated$count <- NA
##  set first value as 1
primary_duplicated$count[1] <- 1
##  set count of duplicates to 1 greater than the 
##  value of the preceding duplicate
for (i in 2:nrow(primary_duplicated)) {
      if (primary_duplicated$md5[i] == primary_duplicated$md5[i-1]) {
            primary_duplicated$count[i] <- primary_duplicated$count[i-1] + 1
      } else {
      ##  set the count value for the first incidence of
      ##  a duplicate as 1
            primary_duplicated$count[i] <- 1
      }
}
```